# Facebook Connect Problems With Grails

Tags: facebook, grails, spring-security

I am trying to use the Grails [Facebook Authentication plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-facebook) but am running into problem. I have (I believe) successfully installed the plugin, put a facebook connect control on a page, and ran the installation script.

When I click on the Facebook Connect button I am correctly brought to Facebook, where I login correctly. At this point the popup closes and nothing happens. I have a custom FacebookAuthService but no breakpoints inside ever get called. I believe I have either 1) hooked up the Service incorrectly or 2) hosed up my Facebook settings so that I am not getting the information back, but I am not sure how to diagnose the problem.

When I run the app locally, it runs on `http://localhost:8080/TestApp`
In my Facebook App Settings I have tried using "http://localhost", "http://localhost:8080", and "http://localhost:8080/TestApp" as the Site URL and I have "localhost" as the App Domain. What am I missing?

Here is a link to the [GitHub Project](https://github.com/skazzaks/Grails-Test) (I've changed the fb private key).

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button authorize you only on client side, because of Facebook Javascript SDK. Please reload page after susseccful authization, like:

```
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (typeof(response) == 'undefined') {
      return
    }
    if (response.status == 'connected') {
      window.location.reload();
    }
  })
```

Comment: Shouldn't the next request to my application be authorized and work correctly? My app is never seeing that I am authenticated. Where would I put the code you pasted? Where can I put in the callback url? Thanks so much for developing this plugin!

Comment: yes, new request must be authenticated (try F5/Commad+R, if not - there is a problem with configuration). This code is a Javacript, that you should put somewhere on your page, into `window.fbAsyncInit` for example. Btw, now I see that I need to make more flexible taglib, because at this point you can't use this handler w/o writing your own JavaScript code

Comment: Since your plugin creates the `window.fbAsyncInit` code, how can I get my `FB.getLoginStatus` code in there? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's the problem, you should make your own copy (and remove taglib usage) :(

Comment: thanks. I ran the test and it is 'connected' correctly. However, my service code never gets called. I copied the example github project and I don't know what I am doing wrong. Do you have a minute to take a look? Thanks. https://github.com/skazzaks/Grails-Test

Comment: Also, it looks like the `.getLoginResponse` code is getting called right when the page loads before login and then not again when the user logs in. How can I get it to be called right after login?

Comment: Does it runs your service code when you've reload current page?

Comment: No, my service breakpoints are never hit and my code to create a user is never called. I don't know how to proceed. Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11197/discussion-between-igor-artamonov-and-skaz)

Answer (score 0):

The JS SDK does not currently have support for non-standard ports in this scenario, but come Tuesday, this will be corrected, and it will once again support it.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any more information? Can I assume it will support it continuously after Tuesday? Is the "Site url" essentially the callback url? Sorry for bombarding you - thank you for your response.

Comment: It will be supported going forward. There is no notion of 'callback url' - the 'Site url' (and others) are simply used to verify consistency between app_id and domain.